# How to set up overload method to find circumference of a circle?

Tags: java, overloading

I'm just learning the ropes of overloaded methods. Here is an assignment in which I have to write the overloaded methods in the incomplete CircleStats class, but I have no idea how to set them up. I am supposed to find the circumference of a circle using its diameter/radius.

I understand that I have to make functions for finding circumference using the diameter, then using the radius, but don't know where to go from there. I also know that the radius will be double and the radius will be int, but am completely ousted with how to fill in the //code goes here part.

It would also be wonderful if someone could explain how to set up the math in each overload method to calculate circumference.Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** In lines 21 and 22, it should be `cStats.calcCircleCircumf` instead of `cStats.calcCircleArea`

```
/* The calcCircleCircumf( ) method in the CircleStatsTester class is overloaded. Write the overloaded methods in the incomplete CircleStats class.*/

class CircleStats
{
    CircleStats()
    {
    }     
    //…code goes here     
}

public class CircleStatsTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int diameter = 5;
        double radius = 2.5;
        CircleStats cStats = new CircleStats();

        System.out.println("The area = " + cStats.calcCircleArea(diameter));
        System.out.println("The area = " + cStats.calcCircleArea(radius));    
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Do you need to implement calcCircleCircumf( )?

Comment: This is all the problem gives meand tells me to write the overloaded methods in the incomplete CircleStats class.

Comment: It is weird, normally they need to at least provide the method signature.

Comment: @user3437460 that's what I didn't understand, I'm assuming the calcCircleCircumf() is used for calculating circumference in the CircleStats class, but have no idea what the cStats.calcCircleCircumf is.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown It is the point of this assignment to find out how to write the method signature and the method body. Look at the two calls, how are they different?

Comment: Holy crap - it's not your fault, but this has to be one of the worst examples of how overloading might be used that I've seen.  Using the type `int` to indicate that a diameter formula should be used, while a type `double` should indicate that a radius formula should be used is a terrible scheme. Surely the instructor could come up with a better exercise to teach about overloading.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You just said exactly what I wanted to tell OP. This is a bad example/practice on method overloading.

Comment: I'm also getting an error saying new CircleStats() is a non-static variable and cannot be referenced from a static context. Jeez this is so confusing

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading means that you have **same** method names, but different method **signature**.

Method signature includes

- Method name
- Method parameter type
- Method parameter sequence

To overload a method, simply create another method of the **same** method **name** with a **different** **signature**.

**Example:**

```
public int getArea(int x)
{

}

public double getArea(double x) //Signature is different, method overloading occurs
{

}

public int getArea(int x, int y) //Signature is different, method overloading occurs
{

}
```

Note that the `return type` **does not affect** the method signature.

---

It is incorrect if you want to implement method overloading, yet providing different method names.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm planning on using, but how can I apply this to the circumference? Also, can you go over the math part too?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown What is the 2 methods you want to overload again? There must be  at least 2 methods involved to let overloading happen.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown I posted another answer. Take a look at it. Is that what you asking?

Answer (score 0):

That is basically impossible.

Overloading a method consists in having two methods with the same name, but with a different signature (i.e. with a different number of arguments and/or arguments of different types).

Since a radius and a diameter have the same type, Java has no way to distinguish

```
calcCircleCircumf(double radius)
```

from

```
calcCircleCircumf(double diameter)
```

So you need two methods with different names:

```
computeCircumferenceFromRadius(double radius)
computeCircumferenceFromDiameter(double diameter)
```

and this is not overloading anymore.

Note about naming: these methods are part of a class named CircleStats. So puttin "Circle" in the method name is redundant and only adds noise. Using complete words makes the code more readable though, and that's the convention in Java. Hence `computeCircumferenceFromRadius`and not `calcCircleCircumf`.

Comment: the radius is double, diameter is int

Comment: @ArnoldBrown then you can overload, but that's awful design. Why would you use a double for one and an int for the other? What is the diameter of a circle with radius 1.3? Is it 2? Is it 3? No, it's 2.6. And 2.6 is a double. Even assuming that this would make sense, choosing the same name for two methods doing something completely different is awful. Make your code readable.

Comment: I only have to use the given values, which are radius = 2.5 and diameter =5

Comment: @ArnoldBrown: you're not learning Java to complete this exercise. You're learning Java to become a decent Java developer. What I'm saying here is that, even though your teacher is asking you to do that, it's not something you should ever do. diameter and radius should have the same type, and the method names should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this looks odd to me, but I think this is what you are asking.

```
public int calcCircleCircumf(int radius)   
{
    return (int)(2 * Math.PI * radius);
}

public double calcCircleCircumf(double diameter) //method overloading
{
    return (2 * Math.PI * (diameter/2));
}
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is something like what the problem wants me to do. Is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: No other way, unless the parameter datatype is the same but different number of arguments.